# Is inline code formatting for comments broken?

Tags: bug, comments, code-formatting, formatting

Just noticed this today on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235254/optional-vs-if-else-if-performance-java-8/56235329#comment99115403_56235254):
[image]

It seems that the formatting is broken, there are lots of whitespaces inside of the inline-code and the grey background is extending beyond the actual comment.

This doesn't seem to be intended.

Could reproduce it on:

- Microsoft Edge - Version 88.0.705.74 (Official build) (64-bit)
- Google Chrome - Version 88.0.4324.190 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Funny thing is, it works (somewhat) fine in Firefox - 78.6.1esr (64-bit):
[image]

Comment: What seems broken is a user inserting a comment with way too much white-space inside a code-formatted line within a comment. It's hard to manage these cases.

Comment: This has been fixed previously, but apparently there's a regression that only affects Chrome (Firefox/EdgeHTML is fine). It [used to only affect Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227187/369403), which is odd

Comment: @ErikA thats weird with firefox. Also I wouldn't close this question as a duplicate because the proposed one didn't get an answer and was lost to time.

Comment: @Lino That's not a reason for not marking it as a duplicate. That's a reason for not deleting it. There's also one [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361250/369403) at the moment, if we leave them open staff will have to answer in three different places and duplicates are still visible.

Comment: @ErikA agreed, I didn't see the new cross site duplicate.